# "Englishize" word order in German while maintaining second position

Tags: word-order

Which one of the translation below is correct German and why?

> - I waited five hours in line.
>
> > - Ich habe fünf Stunden in der Schlange gewartet.
> > - Ich gewartet fünf Stunden in der Schlange.

Comment: _"Ich gewartet fünf Stunden in der Schlange."_ is totally wrong. Why? Because it's totally wrong.

Comment: Why is it wrong? It makes sense to me.

Comment: Can you point me to an answer that I can read up?

Comment: let me read up on past tense sentence structure.

Answer (score 4):

German is not an English dialect! It is a full language on its own. It not only has its own vocabulary, but also its own grammar (and its own pronunciation). It's true, since both languages have a common ancestor (about 1500 years ago) they have many similarities.

But 1500 years is a long time, and in 21st century there are much more differences than common parts. German has 3 genders for nouns which Englisch doesn't have (English has genders only for pronouns, not for nouns). German has 4 grammatical cases (again: English has cases only for pronouns, and only 3 of them), a different system of tenses (there is no continuous form in German), a different word order and many other different features.

So you can't take grammatical features from one language and use it to build a sentence in the other language. This will only work in some few cases where by accident there is a coincidence.

---

There is a tense that perfectly matches with the word order of your sentence, but in this tense the verb has to be in another form. This is correct:

> Ich **wartete** fünf Stunden in der Schlange.

This tense is called *Präteritum,* sometimes also *Imperfekt.*

The other German past tense can only be built with an auxiliary verb, which only can be a form of *sein* or of *haben.* The verb *warten* needs *haben*, so it has to be:

> Ich **habe** fünf Stunden in der Schlange **gewartet.**

And here the German word order says: The auxiliary verb has to stand on position 2, and the full verb must stand at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

*gewartet* is the participle form.

One can use *wartete* instead.

> Ich   wartete  fünf Stunden in der Schlange